# Parse a date/time string in specific format

Tags: c#

I receive some file from external system, the date/time is represented as `28/Jul/2015:01:02:36 -0500`.

What is the best way to parse it in to `DateTime` type in C#?

Comment: That looks like a pretty weird format to me. My guess would be you're going to need to use some combination of [Regex](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex(v=vs.110).aspx) methods and the [DateTime.Parse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1k1skd40(v=vs.110).aspx) method.

Comment: @DanForbes yup, it is from WebSEAL log file.

Comment: Could you confirm that there is no space and a colon between the year and the hour and there is a space between seconds and -0500?

Comment: @Steve I confirm. What you see is what I copied from log file as is.

Comment: You may want to consider using `DateTimeOffset` instead of `DateTime`.  Especially if `-05:00` is not an offset in your time zone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this?

```
DateTime d;
DateTime.TryParseExact(target,"dd/MMM/yyyy:hh:mm:ss zzzz", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, out d);
```

Answer (score 5):

You should look here for more information on Custom Date Formats in C#:

[Custom Date Formats on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx)

However here is some code to get you started.

First, determine the correct format string you expect.  and then use `ParseExact`

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var date = "28/Jul/2015:01:02:36 -0500";
    var formatstring = "dd/MMM/yyyy:HH:mm:ss K";

    var d = DateTime.ParseExact(date, formatstring, null);
    Console.WriteLine(d);
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

try

```
CultureInfo provider = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
var dateString = "28/Jul/2015:01:02:36 -0500";
var format = "dd/MMM/yyyy:hh:mm:ss zzzz";
var date = DateTime.ParseExact(dateString,format,provider);
```